# How have I single handly re-opened a question?

Tags: support, review-queue

So I was doing the re-open review queue and came across [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/62761). I felt it was valid and needed re-opening, but for some reason after my vote the question became open again.

I expected that it should have gone by someone else before it was re-opened, as an example [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/62444) required several reviewers to check it before it had chance of being re-opened.

What was different about the first question?

Comment: you're a wizard harr... @Draken

Comment: Funny story, on the same question, I cast a close vote and it got closed immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It already had 4 reopen votes, so when you said "reopen" it was just reopened because it then had 5 votes.

[You can see you were the fifth reopen vote here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/98923/revisions). But on [the other question you were 2/5](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/98342/revisions).

Comment: Look, more magic!

Comment: For the record, I remember that any gold tag badge user can Single-handedly open/close posts with that tag, so if you eventually get a gold tag badge you might be able to do this without going through other votes. That or being a mod also grants you those privileges I believe.

Comment: @GrayCygnus only if it was closed as a duplicate, though.

Comment: Question then, why does it not show the other votes in the audit screen of the first post but does show it for the 2nd one?

Comment: @Draken my guess is those reopen votes weren't cast as part of the audit, but just "normal" reopen votes.

Comment: Thanks, that was the bit that threw me. Just seemed odd only my name was there!